# Somar total parcial linhas criadas dinamicamente com o jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Nova Compra:</h1>
    <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2">
        <?php

        if ($this->session->userdata('perms') == 1 or $this->session->userdata('perms') == 5) { ?>
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url().'Compras/inclui'; ?>" role="button">Nova Compra</a>
        <?php } else { ?>
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="#" role="button" disabled>Nova Compra</a>
          <?php
        }
        ?>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container float-right" id="body">

    <form id="form" action="<?php echo base_url().'Compras/cadastraCompra'; ?>" method="POST">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="num_nota" onkeyup="maiuscula(this)" placeholder="Número da Nota" required >
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="datac" placeholder="Data da Compra" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id = "qt" name="qt" min="1" max="99" placeholder="Qt. Itens Nota" value="1" required>
        </div> 
        <div class="col">
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="#" role="button" onclick="alert('Neste campo, à esquerda, digite a quantidade de itens da nota!');"> &#xe091;</a>
        </div>
        

        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control money3" maxlength="15" name="valort" placeholder="Valor Total da Nota (R$)" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>

    </br></br>

    


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">




         <input type="text" id="autouser" class="form-control" name="fornec" onchange="ApenasLetras(e, t)" placeholder="Qual é o Fornecedor?" required>



         

         <input type="hidden" id="userid" name="idfornec" value="0">

         <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#autouser').autocomplete({
              source: function(request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                  url:'<?php echo base_url().'Compras/fornecList'; ?>',
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                    search: request.term
                  },
                  success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                  }

                });
              },
              select: function(event, ui){
                $('#autouser').val(ui.item.label);
                $('#userid').val(ui.item.value);

                return false;
              }

            });
          });
        </script>

        
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="obs" placeholder="Observações...">
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <h5>DADOS DO PRODUTO:</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h5>Unit.:</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h5>R$:</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h5>Qt.: <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="#" role="button" onclick="alert('Verifique a unidade do Produto! EXEMPLO: Se a unidade do produto for KG e foi comprado meio quilo, lance na nota de compra a quantidade de 0,50.');">&#xe091;</a></h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h5>Total R$:</h5>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="origem">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" class="auto form-control" id="autoprod" name="prod[]" placeholder="Produto..." required>

        <input type="hidden" id="prodid" name="prodid[]" value="0">

        <script type="text/javascript">


          $(document).ready(function(){

            var i = 0;

            $('#autoprod').eq(i).autocomplete({
              source: function(request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                  url:'<?php echo base_url().'Compras/prodList'; ?>',
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                    search: request.term
                  },
                  success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                  }

                });
              },
              select: function(event, ui){
                $('#autoprod').eq(i).val(ui.item.label);
                $('#prodid').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#marca').val(ui.item.marc);
                $('#unit').val(ui.item.uni);

                return false;
              }

            });
          });





        </script>


      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2">
      <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marca" name="marca[]" placeholder="Marca..." readonly>

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group">



        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="unit" name="unit[]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lugar" name="unit2[]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly> 

        <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){

          $("#autoprod").on('blur', function() {
            var txt = $('#unit').val();

            var jtxt = {
              'valor1': txt
            };

            $.ajax({    
              url: '<?php echo base_url()."Compras/ajax"; ?>',  
              type: 'post',       
              data: jtxt,  
              dataType:'json',
              success:function(resultado) {

                $("#lugar").val(resultado[0].nome_unit);


              },
              error:function(){
                alert("Este produto não existe... Preencha corretamente o formulário!");

              },



            });

          });
        });




      </script>




    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="col">
    <div class="input-group">

      <input type="text" class="form-control money3" maxlength="15" id="valorunit" name="valorunit[]" placeholder="Preço Unit. (R$)" required>

    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="input-group">

      <input type="text" class="form-control quantt" id="quant" name="quant[]" min="0" max="999" placeholder="Quantidade" href="#" value="0,00" required>

    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="input-group">

      <input type="text" class="form-control totalt" maxlength="15" id="totalp" name="totalp[]" placeholder="Total (R$)" required readonly>

    </div>

    

  </div>
</div>
</br>
</div>

<div id="destino">

</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="container text-right col-md-9 ">

   <h5>TOTAL NOTA: </h5> 
   
   
 </div>


 <div class="container col-md-3 justify-content-end">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="15" id="totalgeral" name="totalgeral" value="0.00" required readonly>

</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function(){


    $("#qt").on('blur', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      document.getElementById("qt").readOnly = true;
      document.getElementById("destino").innerHTML=""; 

      var qtr = $("#qt").val();

      var i = 1;


      // WHILE

      while (i < qtr) {

        var z = i - 1;


        var t = '<div class="row" ng-app="">\<div class="col-3">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="autot form-control" name="prod[]" placeholder="Produto..." required>\<input type="hidden" class="idr" name="prodid[]" value="0">\</div></div>\<div class="col-2">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="nname form-control" name="marca[]" placeholder="Marca..." readonly>\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="hidden" class="uunit form-control" name="unit[]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly>\<input type="text" class="llugar form-control" name="unit2[]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly>\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="form-control money3" maxlength="15" name="valorunit[]" placeholder="Preço Unit. (R$)" required ng-model="pu">\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="form-control quantt" name="quant[]" min="0" max="999" placeholder="Quantidade" value="0,00" href="#" required ng-model="qtt">\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="form-control totalt" maxlength="15" name="totalp[]" placeholder="Total (R$)" required readonly>\</div></div></div></br>';

        $("#destino").append(t);

        i = i + 1;


      }

      // WHILE


   $(document).on("focus", ".autot", function(){ //PARENTESES E CHAVE

   // este "if" evita que se aplique novamente ao que já foi aplicado
   if( !$(this).hasClass("ui-autocomplete-input") ){

    // AUTOCOMPLETE
    $(this).autocomplete({
     source: function(request, response) { //CHAVE

      $.ajax({ //AJAX
       url:'<?php echo base_url().'Compras/prodList'; ?>',
       type: 'post',
       dataType: 'json',

       data: { //CHAVE
        search: request.term
      }, //FECHA CHAVE

      success: function(data){ // CHAVE
        response(data);
      } //FECHA CHAVE

    }); //AJAX

    }, //CHAVE

    // ABRE CHAVE
    select: function(event, ui){
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);

      $(this).closest('.row').find('.idr').val(ui.item.value);

      $(this).closest('.row').find('.nname').val(ui.item.marc);

      $(this).closest('.row').find('.uunit').val(ui.item.uni);


      return false;
    } // FECHA CHAVE

  }); // AUTOCOMPLETE
}// IF
}); //PARENTESES E CHAVE

 });
  });




  $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on("blur", ".autot", function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    var txt = $this.closest('.row').find('.uunit').val();


    var jtxt = {
      'valor1': txt
    };

    $.ajax({    
      url: '<?php echo base_url()."Compras/ajax"; ?>',  
      type: 'post',       
      data: jtxt,  
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(resultado) {

        res = resultado[0].nome_unit;


        $this.closest('.row').find(".llugar").val(res);


      },
      error:function(){
        alert("Este produto não existe... Preencha corretamente o formulário!");

      },



    });

  });
 });



  $(document).ready(function($){
   $(document).on("focus", ".money3", function(){
    $(this).mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
  });
 });

   $(document).ready(function($){
   $(document).on("focus", ".quantt", function(){
    $(this).mask("000.000.000.000.000,00", {reverse: true});
  });
 });



  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("blur", ".quantt", function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    var valor1 = $this.closest('.row').find('.money3').val().replace('.','');
    valor1 = valor1.replace(',','.');
    valor1 = parseFloat(valor1);

    var valor2 = $this.val().replace('.','');
    valor2 = valor2.replace(',','.');
    valor2 = parseFloat(valor2);

    var total = valor1 * valor2;

    $this.closest('.row').find('.totalt').val(total.toFixed(2));


  });
 });

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("blur", ".quantt", function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    var total = 0;

    $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').each(function () {

        var soma = $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').val();
        if (!isNaN(soma)) total += soma;
                        
    });

    
     $('#totalgeral').val(total);

    });
 });




</script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="container col-md-1">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">INCLUIR</button>
    
  </div>

  <div class="container col-md-2">

    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo base_url().'Compras/inclui'; ?>" role="button">LIMPAR FORMULÁRIO</a>
    
    
  </div>





  <div class="container col-md-8">
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url().'Compras/index'; ?>" role="button">CANCELAR</a>
    
  </div>

  
</div>



</form>

</div>
</main>

<script type="text/javascript">
// INICIO FUNÇÃO DE MASCARA MAIUSCULA
function maiuscula(z){
  v = z.value.toUpperCase();
  z.value = v;
}
//FIM DA FUNÇÃO MASCARA MAIUSCULA
</script>
```

É uma nota de compra, linha dinâmica tem um subtotal e no final um input que vai ficar com o total geral da nota...

As linhas são criadas dinamicamente, então para calcular o total utilizei o `each()`, mas a cada calculo de subtotal ele muda o valor total para igual a este subtotal ao invés de acumular...

veja o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("blur", ".quantt", function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    var total = 0;

    $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').each(function () {

        var soma = $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').val();
        if (!isNaN(soma)) total += soma;
                        
    });

    
     $('#totalgeral').val(total);

    });
 });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria interessante [edit] a pergunta adicionando um trecho do HTML que possa ser útil para quem for responder.

Comment: Posta o trecho da tabela em HTML/PHP

Comment: Coloca um console.log(total) depois do `if (!isNaN(soma)) total += soma;` pra ver o valor que tá setando nele em cada loop

Comment: Postei o html...

Comment: Edward Ramos o total sempre fica igual ao total parcial de cada linha...

Comment: @Sam Help por favor!

Comment: Aqui eu não entendi `$this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').each(...` proque não é algo similar a `$(document).find('input[name="totalp[]"]').each(...` ? E por que não usa os parâmetros disponíveis para o callback?

Comment: Augusto Vasques, não sei usar o parâmetros de callback... Pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1):

Até funciona, mas não da forma correta... Não ficou bom... Toda vez que o usuário faz alguma alteração num campo dinâmico que já foi somado, ele agrega este novo calcúlo, após o evento "blur" na soma... Não sei como fazer para ele recalcular tudo novamente; ou em último caso, impedir que ele considere um campo que já foi somado novamente... Alguém consegue resolver o enigma??

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(document).on("blur", ".quantt", function(){

      var $this = $(this);


      $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').each(function () {

        var soma = $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').val();
        if (!isNaN(soma)) total += parseFloat(soma);


        $('#totalgeral').val(total.toFixed(2));

      });


    });

  });
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o valor total está sendo calculado corretamente? Essa query dentro do seu loop me parece que vai resultar num erro, pois você está buscando todos os inputs novamente ao invés de iterar sobre os inputs já encontrados.

Comment: User140828 vc tem razão, do jeito que está, está até calculando certo, mas qualquer onblur (evento) que se repita num campo que já passou, na hora de recalcular ele ao invés de desconsiderar o valor anterior do campo, ele só agrega os valores... Ou seja a soma sempre aumenta... Não sei como fazer da forma correta...

Answer (score 0):

apesar desse codigo correr no document ready.... e n teres funções isoladas o que seria bem melhor. 
para saberes que o input mudou podes usar isto:

```
    $("input").bind("input", function () {
            $(this).val();
        });

        $("input").on("input", function () {
            $(this).val();
            // chama aqui a soma;            
        });
```

o melhor seria recrever isso tudo(está uma trapalhada), exemplo:

```
    if (!isNaN(soma)) --> para quê? é o mesmo que --> if(soma)
soma == 0 false; soma == null false etc...
```

o correcto seria:

```
  var soma = 0;
  soma += soma mais coisa ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexandre, o seu código está repleto de PHP e AJAX que não dá para ser simulado, a menos que você crie um exemplo verificável do seu problema não tem como te oferecer uma boa ajuda, mas eu vou tentar clarear o erro de código que você postou. Pode ser que existam mais erros.

No seguinte loop:

```
$this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').each(function () {

    var soma = $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').val();
    if (!isNaN(soma)) total += soma;

});
```

O que você está fazendo aqui, é basicamente procurar todos os `input` com o nome `totalp[]`, e para cada um deles, você faz outra query para encontrar todos esses mesmos inputs novamente.

Quando você utiliza o método `val()` do jQuery, o jQuery te retorna o valor do primeiro elemento que ele encontrou. Como você está encontrando a mesma lista em todas as iterações do loop, todas as chamadas do `val()` irá te retornar o valor do primeiro elemento encontrado.

Para capturar o valor do input atual, poderia estar declarando esse input como argumento no callback do `each()`. O primeiro argumento do `each()` é o índice da iteração, e o segundo é o próprio valor, no caso, o input.

Então você teria:

```
$this.closest('.row').find('input[name="totalp[]"]').each(function(i, input) {

    if (!isNaN(input.value)) total += parseFloat(input.value);

});
```

É claro, com jQuery você também pode utilizar `this` contanto que a sua função de callback não seja uma `arrow function`, e lembre de reatribuir `0` para `total` toda vez que o loop rodar.

Seguindo essa ideia, e com algumas alterações na sintaxe do código, acredito que o seguinte seja o que você precisa:

```
$(() => {
    $('.quantt').on('input', (evt) => {
        var total = 0;

        $(evt.currentTarget)
            .closest('.row')
            .find('input[name="totalp[]"]')
            .each((i, input) => total += Number(input.value) || 0);

        $('#totalgeral').val(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: user140828, não querendo abusar, mas já abusando, vc poderia me dizer o que eu colocaria de acordo com o que tá ai, no lugar de "i" e de "input" ? O que é cada coisa ai no meu código... Não consigo visualizar... Desculpe a minha ignorância...

Comment: @Alexandre, `i` e `input` são apenas argumentos, eles podem ter qualquer nome. O valor deles são definidos pelo `jQuery`, como explicado, o `each` irá percorrer a sua lista de elementos, o argumento `i` terá o valor dos índices (`0`, `1`, `2`...) enquanto `input` é o próprio elemento (na primeira iteração do loop `input` é o elemento no índice 0, na segunda iteração é o elemento no índice 1, e assim por diante).

Comment: @Alexandre, e desculpe um erro meu, eu acabei supondo que o `jQuery` deveria ter o método `input` como atalho para capturar eventos do tipo input, mas parece que não é o caso. É necessário utilizar `.on('input')` mesmo.